# Do all ethereum based currencies need to be mined?

Tags: mining

I am reading about an ethereum based currency called atonomi. It's doing an ICO. I wanted to ask if all ethereum based currencies need to be mined or they could be pre-mined too?

Answer (score 2):

Ether is the only cryptocurrency in the Ethereum blockchain which needs to be mined. Ether is the native currency and the whole Ethereum blockchain works around that.

In Ethereum it is possible to create different kinds of "sub" cryptocurrencies called tokens. These are simply a programmatical ledger ("who owns how many of these tokens which I just created out of thin air") created by anyone.

So any cryptocurrency which uses the Ethereum blockchain and is not Ether itself is a token and it does not use mining directly. Mining is needed for token transfers but the mining process does not have any direct relationship to the token itself (nobody earns tokens by mining, for example).

Often when someone creates a new token he directly decides that he wants to create X amount of them - basically he can create as much as he wants to. So in this sense they can be "pre-mined" even if it has nothing to do with mining. But the token can start with total amount of 0 and they may be for example *minted* (created out of thin air) when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Mining is used for Proof of Work but other consensus algorithms have no mining requirement (eg proof of authority). Hence a token can be based on ERC20 and have no mining requirement.